# How to undo effects of freopen when launching a shell?

Tags: c, bash, sh, io-redirection, freopen

A piece of code ties stdout to a file in C using freopen. After this piece of code, a script is executed which launches a shell. The problem is now that all stdout output is going into that file, so any commands run in that shell are being placed in that file.

I've arrived at this script that launches the shell:

```
/bin/sh 1>&2 2>&1
```

Although it prints to the screen, I am not sure how I can verify that it is actually printing to stdout vs stderr. Can someone verify that I've gotten the IO redirection right?

EDIT:
I do not have access to the program that calls freopen, just the script to run.

Comment: Redirect one of the two and see if the other prints the correct output.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not 100% sure what you mean

Comment: Please clarify (with invented names if necessary), the programs and their relationship.  You have your login shell that you use to run a program Program-A (for which you don't have the source, and which uses `freopen()`), and then Program-A runs Program-B (which is a shell script that ends up launching an interactive shell, using the `/bin/sh 1>&2 2>&1` notation)?  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The goal is to get stdout back to stdout.

Comment: Then I fear your are probably forced into the desperation measures I outlined in a comment to my answer.  You can automate the code that instigates the desperation measures, of course, and the shell script that's run.  I think it is fair to say, though, that you're pushing the code beyond its design limits.

Comment: If stdout is the file, then anything going to stdout will go to the file.  stdout is not your tty.  If you want stdout to be the current tty, try `exec > /dev/tty` and redirect stdout to your tty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell fragment:

- Makes standard output (`1`) go to the place where standard error (`2`) is currently going; and
- Makes standard error (`2`) go to the place where standard output (`1`) is currently going.

The second operation is not needed.

### Original answer

More seriously, if the piece of code is invoked with its standard error going to a file, then the shell's output is going to go to the same file.  If you really want it to go to the same place as the original standard output, you need to preserve the original standard output before redirecting with `freopen()`.  You'd do that with:

```
int fd1 = dup(FILENO_STDOUT);

...now do freopen...


dup2(fd1, FILENO_STDOUT);
close(fd1);

...now launch shell...without I/O redirection
```

### Revised answer

Given the scenario:

- A login shell is used to run a program Program-A (for which you don't have the source, and which uses `freopen()` on standard output)
- Program-A runs Program-B (which is a shell script that ends up launching an interactive shell, using the `/bin/sh 1>&2 2>&1` notation)

And assuming you want the standard output of the interactive shell to go to the original standard output, then you can do this with the following code:

#### `launch.sh`

Runs Program-A with extra I/O redirections and environment variables set:

```
set -x
fd -n 32
exec 3>&1
echo "$0: $@"
fd -n 32
FD_COPY_STDIN=3 exec ./Program-A "$@"
```

The `fd` program prints `o` for a file descriptor that's open and a `-` for a file descriptor that's closed.  The `-n 32` specifies 'print status for first 32 file descriptors' (by default, it prints for all possible file descriptors, but hundreds of lines consisting of 64 dashes is very boring to read).

#### Program-A

Shell script simulating your non-modifiable program.  It runs Program-B after changing standard output to go to a file (`standard.output`).

```
set -x
echo "$0: $@"
# Simulate freopen("./standard.output", "w", stdout);
exec 1> ./standard.output
echo "$0: $@"
fd -n 32
exec ./Program-B "$@"
```

(You could, if you preferred, remove the last `exec` and then echo something after `Program-B` exits.)

#### Program-B

This is your revised script — the program run by `Program-A`:

```
echo "$0: $@"
fd -n 32

exec 1>&${FD_COPY_STDOUT:-3}
exec 3>&- 2>&1
echo "$0: $@"
fd -n 32
exec ${SHELL} -i
```

(Again, it would be possible to delete the final `exec` and do something else afterwards in the script.)

The `-i` option invokes an interactive shell.  The `2>&1` redirects standard error to the same place that standard output is going.  The interactive shell prompts on standard error (as I found out again the hard way — though I'd come across the behaviour before).

#### Example runs

The `isodate` command is equivalent to `date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`.  My standard prompt on machine `osiris` is `Osiris JL:`.

Without standard error redirected to a file:

```
Osiris JL: ls
launch.sh  Program-A  Program-B
Osiris JL: bash launch.sh $(isodate)
+ fd -n 32
ooo-----------------------------
+ exec
+ echo 'launch.sh: 2014-05-20' 17:03:59
launch.sh: 2014-05-20 17:03:59
+ fd -n 32
oooo----------------------------
+ FD_COPY_STDIN=3
+ exec ./Program-A 2014-05-20 17:03:59
+ echo '/home/jleffler/soq/New/Program-A: 2014-05-20' 17:03:59
/home/jleffler/soq/New/Program-A: 2014-05-20 17:03:59
+ exec
+ echo '/home/jleffler/soq/New/Program-A: 2014-05-20' 17:03:59
+ fd -n 32
+ exec ./Program-B 2014-05-20 17:03:59
/home/jleffler/soq/New/Program-B: 2014-05-20 17:03:59
ooo-----------------------------
jleffler@osiris:~/soq/New$ ls -l
total 16
-rwxr----- 1 jleffler eng 100 May 20 17:02 launch.sh
-rwxr----- 1 jleffler eng 158 May 20 17:02 Program-A
-rwxr----- 1 jleffler eng 121 May 20 17:02 Program-B
-rw-r----- 1 jleffler eng 208 May 20 17:03 standard.output
jleffler@osiris:~/soq/New$ exit
exit
Osiris JL:
```

With standard error redirected to a file:

```
Osiris JL: bash launch.sh $(isodate) 2>standard.error
ooo-----------------------------
launch.sh: 2014-05-20 17:05:11
oooo----------------------------
/home/jleffler/soq/New/Program-A: 2014-05-20 17:05:11
/home/jleffler/soq/New/Program-B: 2014-05-20 17:05:11
ooo-----------------------------
jleffler@osiris:~/soq/New$ ls -l
total 20
-rwxr----- 1 jleffler eng 100 May 20 17:02 launch.sh
-rwxr----- 1 jleffler eng 158 May 20 17:02 Program-A
-rwxr----- 1 jleffler eng 121 May 20 17:02 Program-B
-rw-r----- 1 jleffler eng 343 May 20 17:05 standard.error
-rw-r----- 1 jleffler eng 208 May 20 17:05 standard.output
jleffler@osiris:~/soq/New$ exit
exit
Osiris JL: cat standard.error
+ fd -n 32
+ exec
+ echo 'launch.sh: 2014-05-20' 17:05:11
+ fd -n 32
+ FD_COPY_STDIN=3
+ exec ./Program-A 2014-05-20 17:05:11
+ echo '/home/jleffler/soq/New/Program-A: 2014-05-20' 17:05:11
+ exec
+ echo '/home/jleffler/soq/New/Program-A: 2014-05-20' 17:05:11
+ fd -n 32
+ exec ./Program-B 2014-05-20 17:05:11
Osiris JL: cat standard.output
/home/jleffler/soq/New/Program-A: 2014-05-20 17:05:11
oooo----------------------------
/home/jleffler/soq/New/Program-B: 2014-05-20 17:05:11
oooo----------------------------
Osiris JL:
```

Comment: Errr, sorry, I should have mentioned that I don't have access to the program that calls freopen, I just know that it uses that method. In that case, is it possible to redirect stdout back to the real stdout? Then again, is there any difference between the 'real' stdout and the console? I'm a little confused at this point about the difference between stdout and stderr.

Comment: Urgh! So, this program does the `freopen()` I/O redirection, and then invokes your shell fragment?  What you've got should work OK as long as you are happy to have the output go to what was standard error.  That is likely to be true for you.

Comment: If that's not satisfactory, then you're getting towards desperation measures.  Maybe add `3>&1` to the code...it is so much easier when programs have names, not descriptions...to the code that launches the unchangeable program, and also set an environment variable FD_COPY_STDOUT=3 or thereabouts, and have the shell script that's run duplicate standard output from $FD_COPY_STDOUT (nominally `1>&$FD_COPY_STDOUT`).  I've not reviewed whether this I/O redirection actually works or not; I'd not be surprised to find it does not.  In which case, you're into `eval "exec 1>&$FD_COPY_STDOUT"` or ...

Comment: Does this solution require further redirection? eg. 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3?

Comment: See my revised answer...tested on a derivative of Ubuntu 12.04 with Bash 4.2.25.  Somewhat to my surprise (but a pleasant surprise), the `1>&${FD_COPY_STDOUT}` notation worked correctly without needing extra `eval` hijinks.  If you run into problems with that, come back with platform and shell version information.  Do test with a second window available in case something goes wrong.  (I didn't need it, but you might if you're tinkering -- better safe than sorry!)